# Make outlook emails display as a separate icon on taskbar

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, taskbar

I realize this is a duplicate. Unfortunately the original question is just answered as "This is a duplicate". and when I look at the original posts, I can see that they clearly don't address the question. At best they insist this is not possible.

The reason I want to know is I have 1 Office 2010 computer that shows a separate icon stack for messages to the stack that contains outlook and reminders, and a 2nd Office 2010 computer that stacks all of these icons on top of each other. I need these two programs to behave exactly the same.

So, clearly, unless these computers are doing the impossible, this is a possibility. I am unsure why these questions are being marked as duplicates if they are not being adequately answered. So, here it goes again:

Below is the original question:
When I open/compose and email in outlook, the window is kept in the outlook stack, as following:

What I'd like to do, is have the emails be stacked as a new icon, so clicking the outlook icon will immediately maximise outlook, rather than displaying the stack.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

#### What I'd like to do, is have the emails be stacked as a new icon

Configure the taskbar as follows:

- Right click on an empty part of the taskbar
- Click "Properties"
- Change "Taskbar buttons" to "Never combine"

[image]